# How to use tf.layers classes instead of functions

Tags: tensorflow

It seems that tf.Layer modules come in two flavours: functions and classes. I normally use the functions directly (e.g, tf.layers.dense) but I'd like to know how to use classes directly (tf.layers.**D**ense). I've started experimenting with the new eager execution mode in tensorflow and I think using classes are going to be useful there as well but I haven't seen good examples in the documentation. Is there any part of TF documentation that shows how these are used?

I guess it would make sense to use them in a class where these layers are instantiated in the `__init__` and then they're linked in the `__call__` method when the inputs and dimensions are known?

Are these tf.layer classes related to `tf.keras.Model`? Is there an equivalent wrapper class for using `tf.layers`?

**Update:** for eager execution there's `tfe.Network` that must be inherited. There's an example [here](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/neural_network_eager_api.py)

Comment: `tfe.Network` will soon be deprecated. Prefer to use `tf.keras.Model`, as Ash suggested; also see the the section on building models in the [programmer's guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/eager#build_a_model).

Comment: The proof that `tfe.Network` has deprecated [is here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/eager/Network). "...`tf.keras.Model` should be a drop-in replacement for tfe.Network in most cases..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tf.layers` and `tf.keras.layer` classes are generally interchangeable and in fact at head (and thus by the next release - 1.9), the former actually [inherits from the latter](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/693b339/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py#L37).

TensorFlow is moving towards consolidating on `tf.keras` APIs for constructing models as that makes state ownership more explicit (e.g., parameters are "owned" by the `Layer` object, as opposed to the functional style where all model parameters are put in a "collection" associated with the complete graph). This style works well for both eager execution and graph construction (support for eager execution is improving with every release). I'd recommend using `tf.keras.layers` and `tf.keras.Model`.

Some examples that you may find useful:

- MNIST in the [`tensorflow/models`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/823da31/official/mnist/mnist.py) repository
- The [programmer's guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/eager#create_a_model_using_keras)
- Other [eager execution samples](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.8/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples) (where the exact same model definition works for both graph execution and eager execution).

Not all existing TensorFlow examples have been moved to this style, but they slowly will.

Hope that helps.