# What is difference between tf.layers.conv2d and tf.layers.Conv2D?

Tags: python, tensorflow

What is difference between `tf.layers.conv2d` and `tf.layers.Conv2D`?

Why `tf.layers.Conv2D` used in example code in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.03247.pdf)?

Here is a full code snippet:

```
class AddCoords(base.Layer):
    """Add coords to a tensor"""
    def __init__(self, x_dim=64, y_dim=64, with_r=False):
        super(AddCoords, self).__init__()
        self.x_dim = x_dim
        self.y_dim = y_dim
        self.with_r = with_r

    def call(self, input_tensor):
        """
        input_tensor: (batch, x_dim, y_dim, c)
        """
        batch_size_tensor = tf.shape(input_tensor)[0]
        xx_ones = tf.ones([batch_size_tensor, self.x_dim], dtype=tf.int32)
        xx_ones = tf.expand_dims(xx_ones, -1)
        xx_range = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(tf.range(self.x_dim), 0), [batch_size_tensor, 1])
        xx_range = tf.expand_dims(xx_range, 1)
        xx_channel = tf.matmul(xx_ones, xx_range)
        xx_channel = tf.expand_dims(xx_channel, -1)
        yy_ones = tf.ones([batch_size_tensor, self.y_dim], dtype=tf.int32)
        yy_ones = tf.expand_dims(yy_ones, 1)
        yy_range = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(tf.range(self.y_dim), 0), [batch_size_tensor, 1])
        yy_range = tf.expand_dims(yy_range, -1)
        yy_channel = tf.matmul(yy_range, yy_ones)
        yy_channel = tf.expand_dims(yy_channel, -1)
        xx_channel = tf.cast(xx_channel, 'float32') / (self.x_dim - 1)
        yy_channel = tf.cast(yy_channel, 'float32') / (self.y_dim - 1)
        xx_channel = xx_channel*2 - 1
        yy_channel = yy_channel*2 - 1
        ret = tf.concat([input_tensor, xx_channel, yy_channel], axis=-1)
        if self.with_r:
            rr = tf.sqrt(tf.square(xx_channel-0.5) + tf.square(yy_channel-0.5))
            ret = tf.concat([ret, rr], axis=-1)
        return ret

class CoordConv(base.Layer):
    """CoordConv layer as in the paper."""
    def __init__(self, x_dim, y_dim, with_r, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CoordConv, self).__init__()
        self.addcoords = AddCoords(x_dim=x_dim, y_dim=y_dim, with_r=with_r)
        self.conv = tf.layers.Conv2D(*args, **kwargs)
        def call(self, input_tensor):
            ret = self.addcoords(input_tensor)
            ret = self.conv(ret)
            return ret
```

Comment: It's torch implementation not tensorflow I suppose

Comment: Please refer https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module

Comment: @bigbounty it's tensoflow.

Comment: Here's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50029121/how-to-use-tf-layers-classes-instead-of-functions?rq=1. My guess is for consistency, since AddCoords is also a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tf.layers.conv2d` is a simple `function`/`method` to compute its input's convolution, so it needs input `feature maps` and `kernel` or `filter` to run this method. One user just call this method to computing convolution.
But `tf.layers.Conv2d` is a `Class` (an OOP concept), you should instantiate it with certain `filter` before you can use it. Once instantiated, you can input different inputs to it and get outputs. One using this `Class` to design and program a new `Class` or a new type of operation for other users to use.

Answer (score 2):

Calling

```
y = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs, **kwargs)
```

is now [exactly the same](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/layers/convolutional.py#L397) as

```
y = tf.layers.Conv2D(**kwargs).apply(inputs)
```

So `tf.layers.conv2d` can be seen as a shortcut whenever you do not intend to reuse the object created by `Conv2D` other than calling its `apply` method.